# keras attention model: how to extract vectors from the attention vector dynamically

Tags: keras, theano, attention-model

I reuse a word by word attention model written in Keras.

I have two sample inputs, `input1` size: [batch size*21*100], `input2` size: [batch size*2]. Basically, input1 is a batch of sentence pair, input2 is a token position list, each row contains the position of the start token and the end token in the second sentence.

For each row in input1, After the word by word attention operation, I got a list of attention vector `r[]` (size: 11*150), now I want to extract the specific vector from `r` according to the corresponding row in input2, I tried something like `r[input[0]]`, but got the error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not TensorVariable.

Googled a lot for several days, tried lots of ways but nothing works. Any one have better idea? Thanks!